# Javascript function that called another function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I got 3 function which the first set cookie, the second close the div and the third one should call the first two in order to perform both at the same time.
Calling the first or the second alone will work but wont work calling the third function. WHy? is it something wrong in the syntax?

```
<script>
function cookie () { .....  }

function collapse() { 
    document.getElementById('pop_up_main').innerHTML = '';
}
function close() {    
    collapse();
    cookie();
}
</script>
```

Comment: `close` is a method of `window` object. Maybe it's a protected name in some browsers?

Comment: You were right. I Called the function "close" with another name and seems like the third function is now calling the other two. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use the name close for your method.